# Is it possible to programatically filter Skype notifications via their API?

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Suppose my Skype integration wants to filter notifications for a user to messages that contain the string "server down". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default Skype for Business (=SfB) can only block URL or attachments as written [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg520952(v=ocs.15).aspx). Maybe there exist an 3rd party application which can do that, but I do not think so. Reason: The problem here is that SfB can perform peer2peer connections (see more [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615041.aspx)). That means if you and your workmade are in the same network and no firewall restricts you both and you both perform a chat together, the chat is done between both of you (without a real server connection; for more infos see the official documentation inside the 2nd link). So a 3rd party software (which might sitting on the server) will not capture that kind of information. So what you might need is a client software on every PC. But what about the mobile clients then? So I do not think that such a software exists or would be possible to build.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can't make heads or tails of Skype docs.. thanks for the links.